# Persisted model via save method does not show up in sqlite3 database. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

i am new to RoR and probably miss something out.
Can you give me an idea what is wrong?

**TestMethod in Unit Test**

test "create" do

```
prices = [12,14,16]
    prices.each {|p| 
        course = Course.new(:name => "j2ee", :price => p)
        course.save!
        puts course.persisted?
    }
#Course.where({:price => 12...17}).all.each do |c|
Course.find_by_price(12) do |c|
    puts c.price
end
```

end

**Commandline Output running the test**

## Running tests:

true
true
true
12
..

like expected.

**But why does't the db table contain rows?**
sqlite3 test.sqlite3
sqlite> select count(*) from courses;
0

This is def. the right database. If i work with fixture data it is inserted correctly and is until the next testrun available.
Thankx a lot!
cheers
rob

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify what testing framework you are using, but generally speaking, testing frameworks cleanup after themselves, which is the polite thing to do.

You did say that it works with fixtures, so you have nothing to worry about. But if you want to manually verify that persistence is working, open the console and type in your test.

```
prompt$ rails c
> Course.new(:name => "j2ee", :price => 12).save!
> Course.all
```

The console prints all courses. Note, if you are using bundler (which you should be), you may need to start the console with "bundle exec rails c".